# Command to apply invisible property to selection

Tags: key-bindings, text-properties, visibility

I would like to have a command that makes selected text invisible, and another to make selected text visible.  Currently I have

```
(buffer-invisibility-spec '(a . t))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c i") (add-text-properties (region-beginning) (region-end) '(invisible a)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c v") (add-text-properties (region-beginning) (region-end) '(invisible nil)))
```

which works if I run the first line in a buffer, but `(buffer-invisibility-spec '(a . t))` throws a `void-function` error when placed in the init file, (I believe) because there is no buffer yet.  I couldn't find any global version of invisibility spec, how would I go about having this load in for every buffer?

Comment: You are trying to bind keys to non-commands. The binding needs to be a function that has an `interactive` spec, i.e., a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buffer-invisibility-spec` is a buffer local variable.
If you want globally set the key you must add `a` to the default value of `buffer-invisible-spec`.

`global-set-key` is a function therefore the argument `(add-text-properties ...)` is evaluated before `global-set-key`. The return value of `add-text-properties` is undefined in the doc. So you bind your keys to some undefined value which is probably not a function.

You need to define commands that you can bind to keys with `global-set-key`.

You also need to be more careful when setting the `invisible` text property. It may be that you destroy already existing settings.

There follows a version that takes care of the above comments:

```el
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))

(defun my-change-invisible-a (b e &optional add)
  "Make region from B to E invisible if ADD is t.
Otherwise remove invisible spec ni region from B to E."
  (interactive "r")
  (cl-loop
   with iv-prop
   for int being the intervals property 'invisible from b to e
   when (or (null (listp (setq iv-prop (get-text-property (car int) 'invisible))))
        (last iv-prop 0))
   do (setq iv-prop (list iv-prop))
   do
   (setq iv-prop (remove 'a iv-prop))
   (put-text-property (car int) (cdr int)
              'invisible
              (if add
              (cons 'a iv-prop)
            iv-prop))))

(defun my-remove-invisible-a (b e)
  "Remove invisible spec a from region running from B to E."
  (interactive "r")
  (my-change-invisible-a b e nil))

(defun my-add-invisible-a (b e)
  "Add invisible spec a to region from B to E."
  (interactive "r")
  (unless (listp buffer-invisibility-spec)
     (setq buffer-invisibility-spec (list buffer-invisibility-spec)))
  (cl-pushnew '(a . t) buffer-invisibility-spec :test #'equal)
  (my-change-invisible-a b e t))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c i") #'my-add-invisible-a)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c v") #'my-remove-invisible-a)
```

Furthermore, note that it might be that the major mode of the buffer adds `invisible` to the `font-lock-extra-managed-props`. In that case one needs to use font-lock to add the invisible specs.

An alternative is using overlays with non-nil invisible specification.

Comment: Ok my, that `cl-loop` thing!

Comment: @JeanPierre IMHO the `cl-loop` over intervalls with property and region is the most simple tool in that case. The `(last iv-prop 0)` is protection against dotted lists. The `(remove 'a iv-prop)` is a sledgehammer against multiple `'a` in `iv-prop`. The strategy for adding `a` is removing all and adding once. That unifies that treatment of removing and adding. Transforming the invisible props to lists is also a sledgehammer in the case of removing `a`. But, I assume here that all other packages handle the invisible text property correctly, i.e., they handle lists as property values well.

Comment: Copy-pasting this into .emacs gives a `void-function` error on `cl-pushnew`

Comment: @LieAlgebraCow I have added `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))` that should avoid the problem.

Comment: That works, thanks! Also good to have it make sure not to accidentally break other things, since I would not have handled that on my own.

Comment: I just noticed that it's not using the ellipsis to replace invisible text, although the code looks to me like it should be.  How would I adjust to get that?

Comment: @LieAlgebraCow That means that `buffer-invisibility-spec` is set in that buffer (in the major-mode function or in some minor-mode). In `my-add-invisible-a` we can make sure that `(a . t)` is element of `buffer-invisibility-spec`.

Comment: @LieAlgebraCow Moved adding `(a . t)` to `buffer-invisibility-spec` from top-level to `my-add-invisible-a`.

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is to use libraries [`zones.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zones.el) and [`isearch-prop.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el).

- `zones.el` is about defining and using sets of zones of contiguous text. In this case, you use only one zone, defined by the region.
- `isearch-prop.el` is about isearching text-property or overlay-property contexts.  Visibility is just one kind of property.

(You can do the same thing using just `isearch-prop.el`, but zones makes it even simpler.)

```el
(require 'zones)
(require 'isearch-prop)

(defun hide-region (beg end)
  "Hide the text in the region (make it invisible)."
  (interactive "r")
  (isearchp-make-zones-invisible `((,beg ,end)) nil t))

(defun show-region (beg end)
  "Show the invisible text in the region."
  (interactive "r")
  (isearchp-make-zones-visible `((,beg ,end)) nil t))
```